# Seach all types and all indexes in elasticsearch using NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Everybody,
I use .net NEST library to query ElasticSearch. There is a problem on search operation.
I want to search all documents in all types of all indexes.

How can I search all documents without determining document Type? and how can I convert retrieved results to Json or objects like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After investigations I found this code which helped me:

```
client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
      .AllIndices()
      .AllTypes()
      .Query(q => q
             .QueryString(qs => qs.Query(query)
      )));
```

which searchs on all indexes and all types.
of course the other way is to use:

```
client.Raw.Search()
```

function and pass the every details of query in raw json format.

and for converting to json, best option is using `JsonValue.Parse()`